# Form not clickable until setInterval has been cleared in React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Link to sandbox replecating the behavior
[sand box demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-sky-g7zu0?file=/src/App.js)

I have a hook in a React component that I am using as a countdown for time to answer a question.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
     const timer = setInterval(() => {
          setTimeLeft((newTimeLeft) => newTimeLeft <= 0 ? 0 : newTimeLeft - 1);
     }, 50);

     return () => {
          if(timeLeft <= 0){
               clearInterval(timer);
          }
     };       
}, []);
```

My form is very simple

```
<form>
     <FormControl>
          <RadioGroup aria-label="trivia" name="trivia" value={choice} onChange={handleUserChoice}>
               {radioOptions}
          </RadioGroup>
          <Button variant="outlined" color="secondary" onClick={checkAnswer}>Check Choice</Button>
     </FormControl>
</form>
```

`radioOptions` is a list of Radio Components making up the choices of answer.

```
radioOptions = currentQuestion.questionInfo.choices.map((option) => {
     return (
          <FormControlLabel key={option} value={option} control={<Radio />} label={option} />
     )
})
```

The form is not interactive until after the countdown finishes and clearInterval is called.
I can't click to select any of the radio options in choices. The button works and triggers its function. But the radio options arent interactive until the interval is done.

Comment: your sandbox is empty, check link

Comment: Just check and its there? any update?

Comment: yes, its updated now, running some tests

Comment: I think it has something to do with the function Choices()

Comment: thing is, the entire thing is re-rendering every time you are calling `useEffect` and you can actually see that, just try to select the text of the radio button labels, the "Huey", "Duey" and "Louie" and you will see that it will remove your selection because the entire thing just keeps re-rendering

Comment: Am I implementing the setInterval and useEffect incorrectly?

Comment: I updated to have the choices directly rendered instead of an the function `Choices()` and it works as intended.

Comment: hey I solved it, its just a typo thing

Comment: oh looks like you have solved it yourself, I will write an answer anyway, yea, its the useEffect re-rendering the entire choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the `React.useEffect` is just re-rendering the entire choices as the choices reside in the same class, so the choices are getting selected but as soon as the state changes (which is the counter running), the component re-renders the counter and the choices and it looks as if nothing is getting selected. Running the choices directly from the main component helped and it worked like you intended

```
<div className="App">
  {timeLeft}
  <form>
    <p>Select a maintenance drone:</p>
    {/* <Choices /> */}

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="huey" name="drone" value="huey" />
      <label htmlFor="huey">Huey</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="dewey" name="drone" value="dewey" />
      <label htmlFor="dewey">Dewey</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <input type="radio" id="louie" name="drone" value="louie" />
      <label htmlFor="louie">Louie</label>
    </div>
    <button disabled={timeLeft <= 0 ? true : false} onClick={checkChoice}>
      Check Choice
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. If I have some conditional things that will change the options for choices, where should that logic be? Directly in the return?

Comment: @AlexanderMcComb web pages run on single thread, so its basically like this: display - main thread, logic - also main thread, usually webpages dont have loops but loops will freeze the site, you didn't have a loop, you had a setInterval but that state updating made it like a loop, because almost every 50ms the state is trying to update on the main thread and that is why it looked like it was freezing

Comment: thank you for further clarifying the behavior!